# Why is the convergence of $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f(x)| dx$ a necessary condition for the Fourier integral to converge?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, absolute-convergence

My textbook says: "*Let $f$ be piecewise continuous on every interval $[-L,L]$ and suppose that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f(x)| dx$ converges. Then the Fourier integral of $f$ converges to $\frac{1}{2}[f(x+)+f(x-)]$ at each $x$ at which $f$ has a right and left derivative there.*"

It defines the Fourier integral as $$\\f(t) =  \int_0^ \infty  A( \omega ) \cos( \omega t) + B( \omega ) \sin( \omega t)  d \omega$$ where $$\displaystyle A(\omega ) =  \frac{1}{\pi}   \int_{- \infty }^\infty f(t) \cos( \omega t) dt \\\displaystyle B(\omega ) = \frac{1}{\pi}  \int_{- \infty }^ \infty  f(t) \sin( \omega t) dt.$$

It derives this expression from 
$$
\begin{split}
f(x) = & \frac{1}{2\pi}\left(\int_{-L}^{L}f(t) dt\right) Δ\omega \\
 &+\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{n=0} ^{\infty}\left[\left(\int_{-L}^{L}f(t)\cos(\omega_nt) dt\right)\cos(\omega_nt)+\left(\int_{-L}^{L}f(t)\sin(\omega_nt) dt\right)\sin(\omega_nt)\right]Δ\omega
\end{split}
$$ where $$\omega_n=\frac{n\pi}{L}$$ $$Δ\omega=\omega_n-\omega_{n-1}=\frac{\pi}{L}$$ and let $Δ\omega$ approaches $0$ and $L$ approaches $\infty$.

Here, since (if the following integral is convergent) 
$$
f(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\left(\int_{-L}^{L}f(t) dt\right) Δ\omega=0,$$ $f(x)$ becomes the previous expression without the first term and the book's theorem follows.

**My question** is, in the derivation above, only $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t) dt$ is required to be convergent, so why is the convergent of $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f(x)| dx$, a stricter condition, necessary? Am I missing any details?

Comment: Without checking details, whenever you have sums and limits and double integrals, the dominated convergence theorem might be needed for rigorous justification and the dominated convergence theorem often requires some absolute value function to be integrable. You're probably right that this should have been made explicit if it's in a textbook or lecture notes

Comment: Note that the condition $$f\in L^1(\Bbb R)\iff \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|f(x)| dx<+\infty$$ is not necessary: it is a *sufficient condition* since *it implies the existence of the Fourier transform of $f$*. It is a standard fact of Fourier analysis that you can define the classical Fourier transform in classes of slowly converging functions, typically for $$f\in L^2(\Bbb R)\iff \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|f(x)|^2 dx<+\infty$$

Comment: @DanieleTampieri Is there a reason that the convergence of $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t) dt$ is not a sufficient condition for the Fourier integral to convergence to the function? Can you provide a counterexample to the theorem at the top of my question?

Comment: Harry, no: in my opinion it may be sufficient. Of course I have not proved it but maybe it is not something which is done customarily because the condition $$\left|\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(t) dt\right|<+\infty$$ perhaps requires the use of Tauber's second theorem for the integral, as given by G.H. Hardy in his masterpiece *Divergent series*, i.e. it is simply more difficult.

Comment: In my opinion, this is exactly because the natural language for integration is Lebesgue theory (the Riemann integral is fine on bounded domains but it is an absolute monster on unbounded domains - improper integrals are extremely finicky) and in the Lebesgue sense, this is exactly what you need. $\int_{\mathbb{R}} g(x)\,dx$ converges if and only if $\int_{\mathbb{R}} |g(x)|\,dx < \infty$. Taking $g(x) = e^{-ixy} f(x)$, you get that the Fourier transform exists pointwise for $y$ if and only if $\int_{\mathbb{R}} |f(x)|\,dx < \infty$.

Comment: @DanieleTampieri I would be careful with that remark. The Fourier transform is defined on $L^2$, but not as an integral transform but rather as a limiting procedure of some sort.

Comment: @CameronWilliams, yes, it is true that the Fourier transform of $f\in L^2$ is defined as the $L^2$-limit of the Fourier transforms of a sequence of functions $\{f_n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}\subset L^1\cap L^2$ converging to $f$ in $L^2$. However remember that, strictly speaking, the Fourier integral is an improper (since it is defined in $\Bbb R$) singular (since $e^{iwt}\notin L^1\vee L^2$) integral, thus it is *always* defined by a limiting process.

Comment: @DanieleTampieri I am not sure I follow since you always pair the Fourier kernel with an $L^1$ function making it naturally well-defined in the Lebesgue sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Too long for comment

Let us see an example in which $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t) \mathrm{d}t$ exists
however $B(\omega) = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t) \sin (\omega t) \mathrm{d} t$
does not exist everywhere.

Let
$$f(t) = \left\{\begin{array}{cc}
                  \frac{\sin t}{t} & t\ge \pi \\[4pt]
                  0 & t < \pi. 
                \end{array}
\right.$$

$f(t)$ is continuous on $(-\infty, \infty)$.
We have 
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t) \mathrm{d}t
= \int_{\pi}^\infty \frac{\sin t}{t} \mathrm{d}t = -\mathrm{Si}(\pi)+ \frac{\pi}{2}.$$

However,
$$B(1) = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{\pi}^\infty \frac{\sin t}{t} \sin t \mathrm{d} t = \infty.$$

Comment: +1 Very nice example. this settles the question, in my opinion.